# Best way to store information of using first wizard page

Tags: .net, web-applications, cookies

Understand that the subject should be discussed before. But as I haven't found the proper link explaining which approach is supposed to be implemented for my specific issue, will ask you one more time.

I have a big plenty of users that have access to some wizard where they can go through web pages. At first time they are supposed to change some default settings on the first page. And then choose next link. Every next time if they already updated settings they should get the second page directly (but from here they still have a link to the previous first page). The question is how the necessary information have to be stored and where.

1. Can use cookies and each time depending on the value redirect a user using a jquery script
   (understand that nobody guarantee correct work for all clients)
2. Can save the value somewhere in an application context
3. Can store this state to database

Which one to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have `SettingsN` structure for each page, than you can store each structure in `Request.Session` on postback. This will allow you to check which page is filled out and to have this data on server while user is in process.

Comment: Nope. A user is in process not for only one session. He'll work with the application every day. The first page should be shown for him in the beginning until he confirms his settings.

Comment: Than you should have confirmation status in database and in cookies(copy it from db to cookie every time you find empty data in it). This way you will have your database free of excessive requests.

Comment: Good idea. That's exactly what I've been thinking about.